# How can i create a ruleset to assign values to specific columns, based on searching substrings, in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I am a complete newbie to Python (and Pandas library) and need to recreate some SQL code in it.

My task is quite simple of the face of it, I have a few columns, and i need to search them for specific strings, and if they exist then a value is placed in category columns.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

phone_ds= [('IPHONE_3UK_CONTRACT', 968), ('IPHONE_O2_SIMONLY', 155), ('ANDROID_3UK_PAYG', 77), , ('ANDROID_VODAF_CONTRACT', 973)]

a = pd.DataFrame(data=phone_ds, columns=['Names', 'qty'])

def f(a):
    if a['Names'].str.contains('3UK'):
        company = 'Three'
    if a['Names'].str.contains('iPhone'):
        OS = 'iOS'
.
.
.
etc
```

Is there a better (more efficient) way than listing if statements?

How would i go about adding the results into new columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this, but not sure if it is most efficient. If would follow the same logic as i posted above, if that it would create a function with rules. The rules would look in a list of pre-defined search words, then create a new column for the rules.

Each column would require its own function, so to add 3 columns for Phone, Carrier, Contract Type, i created 3 functions.

shown below:

```
android_phones = ['samsung','xperia','google']

iphone= ['iphone','apple']


def OS_rules(raw_Df):
    val=''  

    if any(word in raw_Df['Names'].lower() for word in android_phones):
        val='android'
    elif any(word in raw_Df['Names'].lower() for word in iphone):
        val='iPhone'        
    else: val = 'Handset' 

    return val


df.loc[:,'OS_Type']=df.apply(OS_rules,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [32]: d = {'3UK':'Three', '(?:IPHONE|IPAD).*':'iOS',
              'VODAF.*':'Vodafone', 'PAY.*':'PayG'}

In [33]: a[['OS','Company','Payment']] = \
             a.Names.str.upper().str.split('_', expand=True).replace(d, regex=True)

In [34]: a
Out[34]:
                    Names  qty       OS   Company   Payment
0     IPHONE_3UK_CONTRACT  968      iOS     Three  CONTRACT
1       IPHONE_O2_SIMONLY  155      iOS        O2   SIMONLY
2        ANDROID_3UK_PAYG   77  ANDROID     Three      PayG
3  ANDROID_VODAF_CONTRACT  973  ANDROID  Vodafone  CONTRACT
```