# creating multiple category columns from multiple values returned from a function

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I managed to develop an answer to a previous problem i had (found here: [How can i create a ruleset to assign values to specific columns, based on searching substrings, in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552587/how-can-i-create-a-ruleset-to-assign-values-to-specific-columns-based-on-search)).

However i am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. I wanted to create multiple classification columns based on strings i search for in a description column.

Currently my strategy is below:

```
android_phones = ['samsung','xperia','google']

iphone= ['iphone','apple']


def OS_rules(raw_Df):
    val=''  

    if any(word in raw_Df['Names'].lower() for word in android_phones):
        val='android'
    elif any(word in raw_Df['Names'].lower() for word in iphone):
        val='iPhone'        
    else: val = 'Handset' 

    return val


df.loc[:,'OS_Type']=df.apply(OS_rules,axis=1)
```

However with this strategy, I will need to create multiple functions with 'almost' identical rules, but with different returned values.

Is there a way to return multiple values from a single function? And apply those across multiple new columns?

e.g.

```
if any(word in raw_Df['Names'].lower() for word in android_phones):
    val1='android'
    val2='pixel'
    val3='vodafone'
```

etc etc etc, then create new columns from those?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#create dictionary of all lists
d = {'android':android_phones, 'iPhone':iphone}

def OS_rules(raw_Df):

    #loop by dictionary and return key of dict
    for k, v in d.items():
        if any(word in raw_Df['Names'].lower() for word in v):
            return k    

#if no value match get NaN, so fillna by default value
df['OS_Type']=df.apply(OS_rules,axis=1).fillna('Handset')
print (df)
                    Names  qty  OS_Type
0     IPHONE_3UK_CONTRACT  968   iPhone
1       IPHONE_O2_SIMONLY  155   iPhone
2        ANDROID_3UK_PAYG   77  Handset
3  ANDROID_VODAF_CONTRACT  973  Handset
```